# Delete Instragram media object?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

Using the Facebook PHP Business SDK v10.0.0, I can create media objects on my Instagram page but is there a way to delete these objects without having to manually do so using the Creator Studio?

Comment: Since https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/ doesn’t mention deletion in any way, I guess you can assume that it is not currently possible.

Comment: @CBroe I guess there's no point using the API then :(

Comment: Frequent deletion of uploaded media is probably not a main use case, I doubt that is something the majority of accounts do.

Comment: The new IG API is still relatively “young” though, so it is possible they might add this at some later point.